# using mouse with pyautogui on extended screens [python]

Tags: python, windows, multiple-monitors, pyautogui

I am using python to move the cursor along multiple screens (using extended display).

The method *pyautogui.moveTo(_row_, _col_)* moves the cursor to the correct position on the main screen, but does not move it outside of it. In windows "Personalize" I set the second screen to the right of the first one, but when I call pyautogui.moveTo(2000,400) the mouse simply moves to location (1366, 400) [the edge of the main screen].

So, how can I use python to move the cursor from one screen to another? I'll be using 4 different monitors in my project

Comment: Check pynput instead, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this is late, but since it comes up in the top Google results, I figured I'd answer for others who are ending up here.

There is currently no solution to this problem (As of 8/13/2018). It is being looked into, but not very hard.

In the meantime, I've made things work on my Windows PC with [the GhostMouse freeware](http://www.ghost-mouse.com/), which has no problem with multiple monitors: